KNeighborsClassifier predict throws "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"
I am writing an image similarity algorithm. I am using cv2.calcHist to extract image features. After the features are created I save them to a json file as a list of numpy.float64:
list(numpy.float64(features)), this is a multidimensional vector embedding.
In a second step I load the data from my json and prepare it for sklearn KNeighborsClassifier.
import numpy as np
import json
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity


with open('data.json') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)

X = []
y = []

for image in jsonData['images']:
    embeddingData = image['histogram']
    X.append(embeddingData)
    y.append(image['classification'])

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

#split dataset into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1, stratify=y)

print('Shape of X_train:')
print(X_train.shape)
print('Shape of X_test:')
print(X_test.shape)
print('Shape of y_train:')
print(y_train.shape)

# Create KNN classifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1, metric=cosine_similarity)
# Fit the classifier to the data
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

#show predictions on the test data
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

When I run this code, I get the following error on the line
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1.13707140e-01 9.81128156e-01 2.89475545e-02 ... 0.00000000e+00
 5.02811105e-04 1.15502894e-01].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

The output of the shape part is:
Shape of X_train:
(36, 4096)
Shape of X_test:
(9, 4096)
Shape of y_train:
(36,)

I tried to use the reshape suggestion
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test.reshape(-1, 1))

, which helped other people with the same problem like in this post, but which got me
ValueError: X has 1 features, but KNeighborsClassifier is expecting 4096 features as input.

4096 being the dimensions of my histogram features.
I tried reshaping X_train as well for it to match with X_test again:
knn.fit(X_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_train)

, but this leads to
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [147456, 36]

At first, I tried a slightly different approach based on a knn example where they trained their model on the iris dataset, but there knn.fit would not accept the training data with the same 2D/1D value error. Then I found this example from pyimagesearch which is pretty much what I want to do, except I have the one intermediate step with the json file. The json however is necessary in my case because I want to add other embeddings later and do not want to recalculate everything.
What I do not understand is why knn.fit accepts the data from X_train, but knn.predict does not accept the data from X_test, which were produced in the same way. Why is the error fixed for one case, but not the other?
I already tried the suggested solutions from this, this and this post, but the solution with reshape does not work in my case, as mentioned above. When I try adding extra brackets like this:
y_pred = knn.predict([X_test])

, I get the following error:
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. KNeighborsClassifier expected <= 2.

I also tried to find other examples, but found very few using similar data structures, and the ones I found did not help either.
I also found this question with the same problem, but the accepted answer is not a solution to the problem.
Here's the json file I read from.

What are the dimensions/shape of X_train, X_test, Y_train? Is the error only on predict and not on fit?

"does not seem to work", details required. [mre] is required, but incomplete. you read from a file but don't provide it.

@rehaqds Yes, the error is only on predict and not on fit. Shape of X_train:
(36, 4096)
Shape of X_test:
(9, 4096)
Shape of y_train:
(36,)

Maybe some data is corrupted. Does the fit work with X_test instead of X_train? Is the format data looks good in your json file around the numbers where there is the error "0.11370714  0.98112816  0.02894755 ..."?

@rehaqds I tried swapping test and train and got the same result: Fit works with X_test and y_test, but predict throws the same error. I also looked at the json, but found nothing unusual there.

According to your code above, the features (X) are from the "histogram" part of the json. But in the 2nd error above you say that the features size is 4608 ! I also saw in your json that there are an embeddingImage part with 512 elements. I notice that 4608 = 4096 + 512 but it is not what shows your code.

@rehaqds You're right, thank you! I ran it again with reshape, and got ValueError: X has 1 features, but KNeighborsClassifier is expecting 4096 features as input. Sorry, I will edit this.

Please note that mods will not intervene in reopening a question. If your question was still left closed after the review (which I am not sure it has been handled yet) you can either edit it again and resubmit for another review or ask for more guidance on [meta].

In your question, there is still a mix of different experiments that you made which makes things quite confusing. I looked at the numbers in the main error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead", the first 3 values come from an histogram part and the last 3 from the embeddingImage just after it so it seems that you tried to concatenate both class of features unlike what we see in the code. Moreover the error message seems to say that at that moment it received only one item and not the 9 expected for the test set.

@rehaqds I'm sorry, I checked, this is again right. I tried many different things before posting this here, some making less sense than others, and seem to have mixed up things. I just went through my whole post and re-checked all the code and errors. I still get the error though. X_test still has the shape (9, 4096), so I do not get why it only receives one item.

ok. that was tricky but the culprit is the metric ! Use metric='cosine' and it should work. In the doc (scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/…) you will find the strings possible and it also says that you can use a function as you tried to do but the function should take 2 1D arrays and return a scalar whereas cosine_similarity() takes 2 2D arrays and return a 2D array. So the error message was not directly to what was given to predict but to what was given to the metric that was called by predict.

@rehaqds Wow you're right, it worked ! Thank you ! :)

@rehaqds my question was reopened today, I wanted to mark your answer as the one that helped, but I don't know how to do this because this is my first post here :)

Thanks for your message. As your question was closed I couldn't write an answer and had to use the comments. Now that the question is not closed anymore, I wrote an answer. It is possible that you don't have yet enough reputation to upvote an answer but normally you can accept the answer by clicking on a check sign next to it.

As there is the error message "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" on the instruction knn.predict(X_test), it is logical to think that X_test doesn't have the good dimensions but as you said X_test does have the correct dimensions so at first sight it doesn't seem to make sense.
Indeed, he error message is somewhat misleading in this particular case as the problem is hidden in the definition of knn 2 lines above and in particular to its metric:
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1, metric=cosine_similarity)

If you change the metric for 'cosine', it will work.
Not very intuitive but in the doc you will find the strings possible for metric and it also says that you can use a function as you tried to do though the function should take two 1D arrays as inputs and return a scalar:

metric:  str or callable, default=’minkowski’ Metric to use for distance
computation. Default is “minkowski”, which results in the standard
Euclidean distance when p = 2. See the documentation of
scipy.spatial.distance and the metrics listed in distance_metrics for
valid metric values.
[...]
If metric is a callable function, it takes two arrays representing 1D
vectors as inputs and must return one value indicating the distance
between those vectors [...]

But if you look at the definition of cosine_similarity(), it says that this function takes two 2D arrays and return one 2D array.
That's why you got the error message "expected 2D, got 1D". The error message was not directly linked to what was given to predict() but to what was given to the metric function that was called by predict() !
